# Can't identify the mistake in my circuit

Tags: soldering, breadboard

After finally deciding to transfer my projects from a breadboard to a stripboard, I managed to put this circuit together, but the soldering was the ugliest thing I have ever seen, so I threw it out and started on a different board. The thing is, this one doesn't work. No matter the amount of tracing I've done, I can't figure it out. It works fine on a breadboard, though.

P.S. excuse the ugly soldering and the damaged track.

[image: Schematic]
[image: The project on a breadboard, but with fixed resistor instead of a potentiometer.]

[image: Top view]

[image: Bottom view]

Comment: SFH203 are photodiodes and you've drawn them as such.  But you've wired them like LEDs. What are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: Whoops, I did not choose the correct parts. I intended to use LEDs for the schematic, not photodiodes.

I'm simply trying to have the LEDs light up when it's dark.

Comment: Test each section to ensure that it works. Short the E and C of the transistor to see if the leds light up. You may have wired them backwards. Next you can short out R1 and the leds should light up. If not, then check that the transistor is wired in correctly.

Comment: Suspicious for solder bridges shorting 2nd to 3rd track, and 5th to 6th track, around middle of circuit. Get solder wick and flux and remove excess solder at all joints.

Comment: @Kartman I shorted E and C and they lit up, but when I shorted the potentiometer nothing happened.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt I tested the tracks with my DMM, and it didn't beep, nor did it display a resistance value.

Comment: Well, the issue was a dead transistor. Replaced it and it worked fine. Thanks for the input.